# Prevent time dependent workflow actions that would be in the past

Tags: time-dependent-workflow

We want to setup some time dependent workflows to send out some emails.  At some point a sales person may want to stop those emails going out - so we have a checkbox that they can tick and the rule notices and removes all the pending actions.

However if they now want to restart those emails, then when they uncheck the box the rule then re-adds ALL the emails again.  So if one of them way 60 days before X and another 40 days before X and we are in fact now 30 days away - then both the 60 and 40 ones get re-sent, even though they are in the past.

Is there a way to prevent actions that would be in the past from getting created (e.g. APEX trigger?) - I really don't want to have to make one workflow rule per email with single time based one in each :(

Comment: I believe if you configure the WFR to evaluate today's date in addition to any other criteria when determining the scheduled events, you will avoid the past-sends.  But I believe to your own post, you'll need a rule for each criteria.